# Laravel 5.5 - DB::statement error with \copy command (POSTGRES)

Tags: database, postgresql, laravel-5

Im trying to use the \copy command from POSTGRES using laravel 5.5, to insert a large file at the DB, but im getting this error bellow.

I tried this way:

```
DB::statement( DB::raw("\\copy requisicoes FROM '".$file1."' WITH DELIMITER ','"));
```

Get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \copy requisicoes FROM '/srv/www/bilhetagem_logs/bilhetagem_... ^ (SQL: \copy requisicoes FROM '/srv/www/bilhetagem_logs/bilhetagem_log1_2018-10-29' WITH DELIMITER ',')

Tried this way too:

```
DB::statement( DB::raw('\copy requisicoes FROM \''.$file1.'\' WITH DELIMITER \',\''));
```

Get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \copy requisicoes FROM '/srv/www/bilhetagem_logs/bilhetagem_... ^ (SQL: \copy requisicoes FROM '/srv/www/bilhetagem_logs/bilhetagem_log1_2018-10-29' WITH DELIMITER ',')

If i execute the command that returns on the error above with psql line command, works fine

```
\copy requisicoes FROM '/srv/www/bilhetagem_logs/bilhetagem_log1_2018-10-29' WITH DELIMITER ','
```

Could somebody helps me? :)

I have to use \copy insted of copy becouse I dont have superuser privilege at the DB.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

> COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to access.

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` command, not a regular SQL command. The only environment where you can use it, is inside of `psql`

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) on PostgreSQL and note this line:

> Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes
>   COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in
>   a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and
>   access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy
>   is used.

`\copy` is a psql instruction, so you do not need to write `\copy`, just `COPY`.

Comment: Hi, This link is in my question, like i said \copy is different from copy. copy needs a superuser privilege (that i dont have) and \copy uses STDIN. But im getting that errors. Tks

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to import data from sql to pgsql database

First export CSV file with separator '^'
Then import same file into pgsql using copy command

```
        $users = User::select('*')->get()->toArray();  
        $pages = "id,warehouse_id,name,email,email_verified_at,password,remember_token,created_at,updated_at\n";
        foreach ($users as $where) {
            $pages .= "{$where['id']}^{$where['warehouse_id']}^{$where['name']}^{$where['email']}^{$where['email_verified_at']}^{$where['password']}^{$where['remember_token']}^{$where['created_at']}^{$where['updated_at']}\n";
        }
        $file = Storage::disk('local')->put('user.csv', $pages);        
        if($file){
            $data = "";
            try {
                $file_path = storage_path('app/user.csv');
                $data = DB::connection('pgsql')->statement("copy public.users (id, warehouse_id, name, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at) FROM '$file_path'  DELIMITER '^' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' ESCAPE '\"';");
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
```